# NSInternalInconsistencyException - Animator is already stopped

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Currently getting the following runtime exception

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Animator <UIViewPropertyAnimator(0x600003f24200) [stopped] interruptible> is already stopped!'
```

Because of the following line of code

```
// other code up here that modifies offsetAnimator
...

// stop any current running animations on offset
if let offsetAnimator = offsetAnimator {
    offsetAnimator.stopAnimation(false) // this line is where the exception gets raised
    offsetAnimator.finishAnimation(at: .end)
}
```

What is perplexing, however, is why this error is **NOT readily reproducible**

```
// doing this doesn't always result in an error
if let offsetAnimator = offsetAnimator {
    offsetAnimator.stopAnimation(false)
    offsetAnimator.finishAnimation(at: .end)

    offsetAnimator.stopAnimation(false)
    offsetAnimator.finishAnimation(at: .end)
}
```

What on earth is happening? Can someone explain to me why this error is occurring?

Why does it seem to only happen sporadically? Shouldn't calling `.stop` twice always trigger it?

Comment: Are you on another thread or in a completion handler?

Comment: @Papershine Everything is running on `main`. Although sometimes, we do see a completion handler in the stack trace. Why do you ask?

Comment: UI elements should be modified on the main thread and sometimes completion handlers could be on other threads... but if everything is on the main thread then that would be weird. Could try using `DispatchQueue.main.async` anyway or check if `offsetAnimator.state` isn't `.stopped` before calling `stop` but it's just my blind guess